# Save custom cart item data from dynamic created cart on order creation in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, orders

> **Important note:** I am not using functions.php for any cart functionality. I am using standalone php files, it has to stay this way.

In Woocommerce, I'm creating a cart dynamically adding a product using:

```
global $woocommerce;
$cart = $woocommerce->cart;

//set the custom item data
$item_data = array();

 $product_id = '121';

 $item_data = array(
 'plain_data' => 'test data',
 'array_data' => array('URL' => 'URL',  'Signals' => 'SIGNALS')
  );

//Add it to the cart
$cart->add_to_cart($product_id, 1, null, null, $item_data);
```

Then I create the order from the cart using:

```
global $woocommerce;
$cart = $woocommerce->cart;

$order_data = array('payment_method' => 'PayPal');

$checkout = $woocommerce->checkout();
$order_id = $checkout->create_order($order_data);
```

But the custom item data that I added **does not get saved in the order.**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't want to use any hook, you will be oblige to set the custom cart item data afterwards once the order is created… So try the following:

Try the following:

```
$product_id = '121';

$item_data = array(
    'plain_data' => 'test data',
    'array_data' => array('URL' => 'URL',  'Signals' => 'SIGNALS')
);

$item_data_keys = array_keys($item_data); // Get array keys


//Add it to the cart
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, 1, 0, array(), $item_data);

// Create order
$order_id = WC()->checkout->create_order( array('payment_method' => 'PayPal') );

// Get an instance of the WC_Order Object
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);

// Loop through order items
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
    // Loop though custom item data
    foreach( $item_data_keys as $item_data_key ){
        // set custom item data
        $item->update_meta_data( $item_data_key, $item_data[$item_data_key] );
    }
    // Save item data
    $item->save();
}
// Save order
$order->save();
```

Tested and works.

> **NOTE:** `global woocommerce` is now replaced by `WC()` since a while.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! But what about if each cart item has unique data? Won't this just apply the same array to each order item? Thanks again!

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks so much!